# Edition downgrade of SQL 2012 Management and Client Tools

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2012

I'm currently looking at a SQL Server which was upgraded (by somebody else) from SQL 2008 R2 to 2012 last year. The database works fine, so apparently nobody noticed that a Standard Edition (SE) instance had been upgraded with Enterprise Evaluation Edition (EEE) media. The two database instances stayed as SE but the Management and Client Tools are EEE.

After 180 days the trial ran out and some things stopped working. I noticed these problems when I did a health check on the server and tracked the cause back to that upgrade (SQL Server's saved summary logs every time you even think about changing it are a great help figuring out what happened).

I now have the correct installation media and the SE license key. But I'm not sure how best to proceed. Just uninstall the existing tools and reinstall the correct ones? I've never run across a situation like this so any experience or suggestions gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out on a test server with a similar setup and the answer does seem simply to be to uninstall via Windows, reinstall from the original media, and then service pack/CU/patch back to the right level.